# TLS 1.3 support for Windows Server 2019

Tags: security, ssl, windows-server-2019

Is TLS 1.3 supported on windows server 2019?
I found a documentation from microsoft but for some reason the matrix doesn't include server 2019: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-

Comment: Based on [Microsoft TLS 1.3 Support Reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/microsoft-tls-1-3-support-reference/) from 20/01/30 I would suggest that it is not supported.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that link is dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Server 2019 is little more than a rebranded Windows Server 2016 which is most likely why it's not mentioned in the compatibility matrix you mention.

If you need to compare, Windows Server 2019 matches Windows 10 1809 (just like 2016 matches 1607) so you can take that for reference.

Feel free to edit the Microsoft documentation to add Windows Server 2019, if the edit is approved that'll actually give you an "authoritative" answer from Microsoft.

Comment: I've created a pull request with the updated documentation. I'll update when the change is accepted

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in a comment, i've created a pull request for the documentation and it was accepted.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-

This means Windows Server 2019 **does not** support TLS  1.3

Answer (score 2):

According to this link, Windows 2019 does not support TLS 1.3.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-

```
Windows OS  TLS 1.0 Client  TLS 1.0 Server  TLS 1.1 Client  TLS 1.1 Server  TLS 1.2 Client  TLS 1.2 Server  TLS 1.3 Client  TLS 1.3 Server
Windows 10, version 1809//Windows Server 2019   Enabled Enabled Enabled Enabled Enabled Enabled Not supported   Not supported
```

Answer (score -1):

Support for TLS 1.3 was included with Windows Server 2019 Build 18362 (1903) and Windows 10 Build 18362 (1903).

Comment: The current official list from Microsoft dated 9/28/2021 is https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp- shows that these versions do not have TLS 1.3 support. Do you have a supporting reference? I did find this article indicating TLS 1.3 support was added to the Windows Insider Preview https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2020/08/20/taking-transport-layer-security-tls-to-the-next-level-with-tls-1-3/ but I can't find any reference to general release of TLS 1.3 in Windows 10 or 2019.